# Building windowsservercore Docker image from scratch

Tags: windows, docker

I'm new to docker, and I work in a corporate environment that is very locked down.  In short, I have docker installed on a Windows Server 2016, but I have no access to dockerhub at all and will not be getting access to dockerhub in the near future, and so I cannot rely upon "from microsoft/windowsservercore" in my dockerfile.

Nonetheless, I need to package a .Net server application in a docker image for evaluation purposes.  Is it possible to build a windowsservercore image from scratch?  I looked for the dockerfile in Github for reference, and while I found the one for dotnet-framework at https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker, I could not locate a windowsservercore docker project there.

Comment: I'd look at setting up a private repository, pulling the images down and storing them on the private repo. It's going to be a lot more sane than what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's what we're planning to do in the long term.  In the short term, I'd like to be able to answer questions about the proposed solution intelligently, and while the Docker documentation is great in general, nothing beats a prototype. 

(I take from your tone that building a dockerfile from scratch for Windows is probably more trouble than just waiting for a large IT organization to come to consensus on a security issue :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images from the docker hub are often maintained by a wide community and trust-worthy. If you're in a closed network that doesn't allow direct access to the docker hub and you want to run this image on the production server anyway, pull the image on your laptop, then use `docker save` and `docker load` to export the image to a tar file and import it on the production machine.

Reference :

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/